# will microsoft edge support override pages?

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

Microsoft edge extensions seems to be much like chrome extensions,
Chrome seems to have a few options to override different pages, 
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override

will microsoft edge support these manifest configurations as well?

Answer (score 1):

There is no definite answer now, but as per the description of [Microsoft browser extension policy](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/extensions/microsoft-browser-extension-policy/), it **seems** overriding existing pages **may** be not supported.

> Extensions **must not** programmatically alter or limit access to browser features including but not limited to: the address bar, **homepage**, search box, **new tab page**, or **favorites**.